# pygame: replacing image of an item/enemy

Tags: python, image, pygame

I'm trying to write a program where the image for the 'enemy' I have changes once its health goes to 0. I have different classes for each element, but I have this under this class.

```
class Enemy(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, gs=None):
            pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
            ...initialization stuff...
            self.image = pygame.image.load("enemy.png") #enemy image
            self.rect = self.image.get_rectangle()

            self.hp = 40  #initial health

    def damage(self):
           if self.rect.colliderect(self.user.rect): #collision/how the health goes down
                                    self.hp = self.hp - 5
```

Now here's the part I'm curious about, I want to load a new image that **replaces** the old image I have for this enemy. Can I do/add (in the damage function)

```
           if(self.hp == 0):
                    self.image = pygame.image.load("dead.png")
```

Will this replace it? Or just load another image on top of it? 
Let me know what I'm missing, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should load all your images into your `init` method when you create the object and then you can do the assigning/changing later using lists. Here is an example:

```
class Enemy(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, gs=None):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.images = [pygame.image.load("enemy.png"), pygame.image.load("dead.png")]
        self.current_image = self.images[0]
        self.rect = self.current_image.get_rectangle()
```

Then later you can do:

```
if(self.hp == 0):
    self.current_image = self.images[1]
```

This will in fact, as per your concern, replace the current image instead of just drawing over it. Hope that helps.

Comment: Good job, but you didn't clarify to them that in fact it does just replace the image, and not just draw it on top of, but other then that, great suggestion to them.